# Finding the variable of the far arc on a circle. With only an angle measurement of the angle outside the circle?

Tags: geometry, circles, angle

Given a circle with a center point C and an outside angle measuring 46 degrees as shown, find what is x. ( which is the outer arc segment of the shaded sector of circle.)

[image: Exactly as described. Not drawn to scale]

Comment: Hint. Join the center to the points of tangency. Then use the quadrilateral to find the central angle, then the angle for the far arc.

Comment: The image seems to depict a pair of *tangents* drawn to the circle (from a common point outside the circle).  One can then ask about the angle *subtended* by the two tangent lines, and possibly your mention of "the far arc of the circle" means that arc consisting of the circle without the subtended arc.  Please edit your Question to include this information if it applies, as no mention is made currently of the lines being tangents. etc.

Comment: @EthanBolker:  that should be an answer, which I would upvote

Comment: @RossMillikan Done

Answer (score 1):

Hint (posted as an answer at @RossMillikan 's  request). Join the center to the points of tangency. Then use the quadrilateral to find the central angle, then the angle for the far arc.